# android keyboard with different language

Tags: android, keyboard

**How to print urdu font in editbox while user press any button of the softkeyboard?**

I want to create urdu keyboard. I have made lots of research on that. I found the solutions. but I couldn't found the way that how to print urdu fonts in editbox when user type? I know about keyboard.xml and other things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple. Just need to add unicode as **android:codes** and it will print that particular char in edittext.

```
        android:codes="0x0AE7"
        android:keyLabel="2"
```

Comment: what to do about the labels,i.e if i wanted to write urdu language lables in the keyboard as well, the unicode will display the urdu key in the editText, but to display the urdu characters on the keyboard, which key will show what character in the editText is my question